# My project crashes with Amazonia but it works in older QField versions (Windows)

Tags: qfield

I have a fairly large project (2.7gb) that with version 2.8 of QField I could open without many problems. It contains cartographic bases in local and WMS. It also has several databases and calculations on the forms with the "aggregate" function. It's not a simple project... When I updated to the new Amazonia version there is no way to open it with the QField. I can't check the log because I can't open it. I've tried all the Amazon versions and they all fail...

Any idea how to find the problem?